# Core Data and Concurrency, 2 solution, which way shou I use?

Tags: core-data, concurrency

I get some data from server and I need to parse it. Then some of the parse result may need to save using core data.

this is my code now:

```
- (void)receiveSomeMessage:(NSString *)message
{
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(parseMessage:) withObject:message];
}

- (void) parseMessage:(NSString *)message
{
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSManagedObjectContext *BGMOC =  [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [BGMOC setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[self.appDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator]];

    //parse it
    //write to core data 

    NSNotificationCenter *dnc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [dnc addObserver:self selector:@selector(addContextDidSave:)    name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:BGMOC];

    NSError *saveError;
        if (![BGMOC save:&saveError]) {
            //handle the error
        }
    [dnc removeObserver:self name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:BGMOC];
}

- (void)addContextDidSave:(NSNotification*)saveNotification {

// Merging changes causes the fetched results controller to update its results
[self.appDelegate.managedObjectContext   mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:saveNotification];
}
```

This seems to work.

But Apple's Document says: Saving in a Background Thread is Error-prone.

So i wonder is this work:

```
-(void) parseMessage:(NSString *)message 

{ NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 
   //parse it and save it to a dictionary
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(saveToCoreData:) withObject:dictionary waitUntilDone:YES];
 [pool release];
}
```

After parse the message,I packet it into a dictionery and pass it to main thread and do the core data thing there. Does this work? if it works, is it better?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html) don't say that saving in the background is technologically error-prone, they imply that ***programmers*** are prone to make errors when saving in the background:

> Asynchronous queues and threads do not
>   prevent an application from quitting.
>   (Specifically, all NSThread-based
>   threads are “detached”—see the
>   documentation for pthread for complete
>   details—and a process runs only until
>   all not-detached threads have exited.)
>   If you perform a save operation in a
>   background thread, therefore, it may
>   be killed before it is able to
>   complete. If you need to save on a
>   background thread, you must write
>   additional code such that the main
>   thread prevents the application from
>   quitting until all the save operation
>   is complete.

Translation: "When quitting, the programmer has to pay specific attention to the save state of background operations and, a lot of the time, they don't."

Comment: I understand that. 
If I do it in main thread, I don't need to create an new NSManagedObjectContext,don't need to merge it to the main thread's context either, it seems simpler.

Comment: The major reason for performing background operations is that the UI runs on the front/main thread so anything that ties up the main thread freezes the UI. Because of lag in server operations, it is almost always a good idea to put server related functionality in a background thread. However, you don't have to save the data there. You can just pass it to the main thread and have it inserted into the context there.